# SQL Server FullTextSearch doesn't work properly for German

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, full-text-search

We have two SQL Servers and on both of them FTS is enabled and should be configured the same way. Both run with the same server version. The SQL Server we have problems with runs in Azure.

I also have checked the wordbreaker language versions with the following statement. Both have the version 14.0.4763.1000 installed for German (1031).

```
EXEC sp_help_fulltext_system_components 'wordbreaker'
```

On one server, we do not get results properly, even though the word we are searching for exists in the table. With the following query we don't get any results:

```
SELECT *
FROM vsTst vsTst
WHERE CONTAINS(vsTst.Content, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, Einzelunternehmen) OR "Einzelunternehmen*"', LANGUAGE 1031)
```

But with the keyword "Einzelunternehm" instead of "Einzelunternehmen" we get the results we are looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM vsTst vsTst
WHERE CONTAINS(vsTst.Content, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, Einzelunternehmen) OR "Einzelunternehm*"', LANGUAGE 1031)
```

We have absolutely no clue what the issue is. Does anybody have the same problem or have any idea what we have done wrong?

Thx